# How to hide list view suggestions after item tapped (selected) event? Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here I have text changed event with predictions which I am displaying in ListView. Also, I implemented the ItemTapped event. When an item is tapped, it is automatically putting those results in the search bar field. That part till now works smoothly. Now my problem is how to hide a list with suggestions after an item was tapped/selected[image]. Below is my code and picture, which explains my problem. Thanks

UI:

```
<SearchBar x:Name="locationEntry"
                   TextChanged="locationText_Changed"
                   Placeholder="Unesi Lokaciju"
                      CancelButtonColor="Red"/>                  
                <ListView x:Name="searchResults" IsVisible="false" 
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemTapped="searchResults_ItemTapped" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding description}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

CODE:

```
 private async void locationText_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {           
            if (location == null)
            {
                await GetLocation();
            }
            string formattedLocation = string.Format("{0}%2C{1}", location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
            var keyword = e.NewTextValue;
            if (keyword.Length >= 1)
                {
                    List<Prediction> predictionList = await VenueLogic1.GetVenues1(keyword, formattedLocation);
                    searchResults.ItemsSource = predictionList;
                    searchResults.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    searchResults.IsVisible = false;
                }                           
            } catch (NullReferenceException nulrex)
            {
            } catch (Exception except)
            {
            }
        }
        private void searchResults_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               if (e.Item is Prediction result)
                {
                    locationEntry.Text = result.description;
                } 
            } catch (NullReferenceException nre1)
            {
            } catch (Exception ex1)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: set `searchResults.IsVisible = false;`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, searchResults.IsVisible = false; is set in UI and in code for private async void locationText_Changed if and else methods are implemented regarding the matter. And it works well. The problem is searchResults_ItemTapped. I tried to set searchResults.IsVisible = false there as well, but it did not work. It is not disappearing after being tapped. Or I missed something potentially there

Comment: is `locationText_Changed` firing again after you hide the list?  Or have you stepped through `searchResults_ItemTapped` to verify that the code is executing?

Comment: It is not firing back in locationText_Changed. That part works smoothly. The issue is in  searchResults_ItemTapped. I want it to be hide after the item is tapped. It  is not firing the searchResults.IsVisible = false; in  searchResults_ItemTapped

Comment: `searchResults_ItemTapped` sets `locationEntry.Text` again, which will cause the TextChanged to fire, which will enable visibility again.

Comment: Oh yeah, now when you pointed it out. It is quite obvious. Is there any way to work around it? How to make it hidden after the selection?

Comment: the easiest approach would be to disable the TextChanged handler until after you've hidden the ListView

Comment: I will try with the mentioned approach. thanks